# Why should Console.WriteLine be avoided in library code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When writing a library to be consumed by other C# applications (some web apps, some AWS lambdas), what are the downsides to writing messages to the console? The messages would be infrequent and unnecessary for operation, but would help in debugging un-common scenarios, if the developer had access to the logs.

The [documentation on System.Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netcore-3.1) says

> Do not use the Console class to display output in unattended applications, such as server applications. Calls to methods such as Console.Write and Console.WriteLine have no effect in GUI applications.

But does not explain why.

Comment: Are `the logs` and `console` synonyms in the context of your question? Or `logs` are file logs?

Comment: "Calls to methods such as Console.Write and Console.WriteLine have no effect in GUI applications" is enough. If such calls can be avoided, the performance can be better, no matter how small the gain is. Also when a console application consumes the library, the developer might not want to see any miserable output from that library but his/her own application. That's exactly why library authors should consider other alternatives for logging.

Comment: [Debug.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Console.WriteLine` in a library tightly couples your library to stdout, and assumes that the calling code (the application consuming your library) is paying attention to stdout. What if your library code is invoked by someone's unit test suite? Or on a web server that is using a different logging paradigm?

You're right that emitting trace and debug messages from library code can be a big help when trying to track down strange issues. Logging in a library isn't bad, but libraries shouldn't assume that stdout is the only way the calling application wants to consume logs. The best ways to do this are:

1. Create a simple `IMyLibraryLogger` interface that ships with your library. If the calling code wants to listen to debug messages, they can implement an adapter that connects your interface to their logging system of choice.
2. Depending on what frameworks your library is targeting, use [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) as a common logger interface. This requires that your library target .NET Standard 2.0.

I've done #1 in libraries I've built in the past and it worked well. It didn't matter if my customer's systems were using log4net, Serilog, etc. My library only cared about the small logging interface it published, and sent messages to it in a safe way (no-op if it was null/not provided).

Comment: Console simply writes to standard output.  There doesn't need to be a console running the program for that to be used; *anything* looking at the standard output can read it.  This is just an objectively false answer.  Lots of programs not run from a console, and with no human looking at the code, will read standard output of a program.

Comment: @Servy just because you can redirect stdout does not mean that they is the preferred logging location for the app the library is in. In a web served the app may send it's logs over the network to a central store, or the app might be a console app where stdout is used as a data output, and logs go somewhere else so they don't interfere with the data.

Comment: If you use console.write, you remove the options for  the application to control other locations log can go.

Comment: @Servey and on windows, not having stdout is the default. Only processes explicitly setup to have a stdout (console apps of various types) native win32 GUI processes do not.

Comment: @user1937198 I didn't say it's the preferred logging strategy.  You said that using Console.WriteLine assumes there is a console, and that's not true.  You don't need a console to use the class.  I didn't say it was the preferred way of logging, just that your assertion that a console is needed is just factually wrong.

Comment: @user1937198 Every process has a standard output.  It's possible nothing is reading the standard output, but *every program has one*.

Comment: @Servy If you build as a GUI app, and don't allocate a console, GetStdHandle returns NULL for stdout. How is that having a stdout? Yes its defined as a place, but its not a file handle you can actually write to.

Comment: @user1937198 You can write to it with Console.WriteLine, and if whatever invokes the app directs the standard output anywhere, it can read whatever's written.  How is that not having a standard output?  If nothing is reading it, then yes, it goes no where.  But when writing the program you can still write to it, and if a consumer wants to use it, they can.  Some programs require the standard output to be read to be useful, some don't.  You can write whichever you want.  But the point remains, saying, that using Console.WriteLine assumes that there is a console is false.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I meant stdout when I said console. I was generalizing while trying to make the point that logging to stdout assumes the calling code will be watching stdout. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: @NateBarbettini Again, you can always write to standard out.  The program doesn't need to care whether or not anything is listening to it, they can always write to it.  If the caller doesn't want to do anything with debugging information written to the standard output, that's fine.